# Get custom post meta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show custom post meta in my page template and it does not show. I am using the code below:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    //
    get_post_meta($post->ID,'rnr_sec-sub-title',true);
    //
} // end while
wp_reset_postdata();
} // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As `get_post_meta()` **returns** value, you should `echo` it:

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'rnr_sec-sub-title',true);
```